# High number of connections on Mongoose 5.6.1

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoose to connect to a replica set consisting of 1 primary and 3 secondary nodes. I recently updated my application from Mongoose 4.9.1 to 5.6.2. I've kept the connection pool size same as before (30) and used the new param `minSize` to set minimum as 2.
I see my application using more connections than before with the same traffic. It's keeping ~20-22 connections open to primary as compared to 8-10 earlier. This leads me to reach the connection limit on my mongodb cluster.

Is there any change in mongoose that leads to this high number of connections being kept ready?

Here are the config options I am using.

```
{
    minSize: 2,
    poolSize: 15,
    autoReconnect: true,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    reconnectInterval: 5000,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `maxPoolSize` option in the connection string (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.maxPoolSize), although the behavior of this option with the connection pool may be dependent on the driver.

That said, a database side connection limit of 20-22 seems really low.

Comment: maxPoolSize option on mongodb would be equivalent to the poolSize option I'm setting on mongoose. 20-22 is the maxPoolSize for my application, not the database.